# What is the purpose of the `sh` command?

Tags: bash

What is the purpose of the `sh` command when used interactively and when used inside of a bash script?

Other than on the hash bang line (the first line) should `sh` ever be replaced with `bash` on a bash system?

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
sh -c "command"
```

Comment: Please, only 1 question per question :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between bash and sh](http://superuser.com/questions/125728/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-and-sh)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because the question would apply equally to any similar shell command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So many questions...  I'll take them one at a time.

1) What is the purpose of the sh command when used interactively?
Provides a new environment context, so if you wanted to experiment with some environment variable setting, you could.  And when you were done, `exit` out and no harm done.

Also, if you were in a different shell like zsh or csh, and wanted to execute in a `sh` shell, this would switch you.

2) When used in a bash script like you have above, it will again provide a contained environment context for "command" to run in.  You can also use it with the

```
#!/bin/bash
sh -c "command" &
```

and fork off "command" to run in parallel with the rest of your script.

3) I would say, if it is something that specifically needs `bash`, then explicitly put it in your hash bang line.  But since on most later *nix systems `sh` is equivalent to `bash`, it is probably not necessary.

Comment: I think your #3 answers the question: "Is `#!/bin/bash` necessary on later systems?" and your answer is no.  As to whether `bash` is necessary instead of `sh` I think you are implying that the answer is only if you specifically need bash.

Comment: "Most later" does not include Debian and its derivatives since they use Dash as `/bin/sh`, so it's quite a large proportion of systems where this isn't true.

Comment: As for your answer "2)": one could do this without the `sh -c` construct by just appending `&` to the command directly.

Comment: Well, the fork off to run in parallel, yes.  To be running it in an independent environment, no.

Comment: @DanielAndersson Thanks for the correction.  I tried to phrase it as best I could, but I knew that 'sh' doesn't always equal 'bash' for all cases of 'sh'.

Comment: @pottsdl: [comment -2]: yes, but the `sh -c` part does not add to the possibility to run in parallel, as you said as well in your comment, so in my eyes it was unnecessary to mention. It's not wrong, but it's not related to the question in itself, imho.

Answer (score 11):

## What happens when I execute `sh`?

If you simply start `sh` on the shell, you'll start [another shell inside your current shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll).

## What happens when I use `sh` in a script?

The same thing, you start another shell inside the shell that is processing the script.

## Should I simply use `/bin/bash` if that's what `/bin/sh` points to anyway?

**No**. If the script was designed to work with ***any*** shell, then it is designed to work against the lowest common denominator between all shells (to my understanding, this is part of the [POSIX standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)).
Changing to a ***specific*** interpreter shouldn't be harmful (because, all of them comply to the same standard) but it reduces compatibility while providing no benefit at all.

## So, I should always use `/bin/sh` then?

### As an interpreter

No. If you're writing a script **yourself**, then you can also use a more specific interpreter (like bash) if that interpreter provides additional features you want to make use of. But keep in mind that everyone who uses your script will be required to have your chosen interpreter.

### To start another process

If you simply want to start a new process in its own context, then, by all means, use `/bin/sh`.

## So what's the point of it all?

If you want to execute something *in its own context*, you should execute it in a new shell.
The easiest way to achieve that is to start a new shell (using `sh`) and passing the command to it.

As long as your *something* isn't a script specifically crafted for a specific shell, there is no reason to invoke a specific shell. Just invoke ***any*** shell, by using `sh`.

If you have a script, that uses special syntax only available in `bash`, then you should set the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) accordingly.

Comment: Even if `bash` and `sh` are the same program are the same on your system, `bash` should work more like `sh` than `bash` if invoked with that name. Scripts using `sh` semantics are more portable than scripts using `bash` extensions.

Answer (score 4):

Why /bin/sh ??

As others have pointed out you get to decide what that actually means :)
(Or your distro does for you.)

For bash at least it has a particular meaning...

From the bash man page:

> " If  bash  is  invoked  with  the name sh, it tries to mimic the
> startup  behavior of historical versions of sh as  closely  as
> possible,  while  conforming  to the POSIX standard as well. "

So if you /bin/sh points to /bin/bash then you get that behaviour.

> #!/bin/bash

gives you "standard" bash **(and its "bashisms")**

of course /bin/sh may actually be a link to say /bin/dash or ksh or some other "shell".

The bash man page is huge but this particular info is only...145 lines in :)

There are a couple of good introductions about:
The Advanced Bash Scripting Guide is excellent.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

If your on Debian / Ubuntu (or other derivatives) :

> abs-guide - The Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide
>
> debian-reference-en -> Debian system administration guide, English original

e.g.

```
apt-get install abs-guide
```

FYI dash: (edited down to description)

> $ apt-cache show dash

says:

> Description-en: POSIX-compliant shell  The Debian Almquist Shell
>
> (dash) is a POSIX-compliant shell derived  from ash.  .
>
> Since it  executes scripts faster than bash,
>
> and has fewer library  dependencies
>
> (making it more robust against software or hardware  failures),
>
> it is  used as the default system shell on Debian systems.

Homepage:

> [http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/](http://gondor.apana.org.au/%7Eherbert/dash/)

Answer (score 3):

`sh` is not a shell command but a program you are calling. Your line will search for `sh` in your path. In most cases it will just execute `/bin/sh` which is in the path.

This will start a new process.

`/bin/sh` is not guaranteed to be bash, it is now on many systems bash but on several Unix system it is the Bourne shell. If you execute `/bin/sh` you can just expect a shell adhering to the POSIX standard.

Comment: And the purpose is... ?

Comment: In your example to start a shell (not mandatorily bash) with the command as an argument. It will execute as a different process (different memory space, possibility to detach it, ...)

Answer (score 2):

1) It's a shell. Its purpose in interactive mode is to read input from user and execute specified commands. In non-interactive mode it reads all commands from script file, so it works without user ever touching the keyboard.

2) The difference between "sh -c command" and just "command" in script file is that in the former case command is forked from separate shell process, whereas in the latter case it is forked from the process running main shell script (i.e. has access to its file descriptors, environment etc.). So we have additional process in the process tree in the former case, and also some degree of isolation.

3) /bin/sh may be symlink to /bin/zsh (for example), so, yes, if you mean to run bash child script from the bash main script you should explicitly say "bash -c". If child script is shell-independent, then "sh -c" will do as well.