# brace expression is not working in HP-UX environment

Tags: unix

I need to create multiple directory.
But when I use following command it is not working -

```
RUN1 ,RUN2,RUN3

mkdir RUN{1..3}
```

Comment: Your "question" is information, not a question. Are you asking "why is it not working?"? Probably because the shell is neither Bash nor Zsh, nor anything that understands the syntax you used. Or is your question different? What is it?

Comment: any solution,,,,how to make it work

Comment: What shell are you using? Can you use other shells? What do you mean by "not working"? Does `mkdir` create a directory literally named `RUN{1..3}`?

Comment: yes it is creating directory RUN{1..3}.
when I am using echo $SHELL
IT prints /usr/bin/sh

Comment: Please see [What is the difference between bash and sh?](https://superuser.com/q/125728/432690) Your `sh` does not expand `RUN{1..3}`.

Comment: any idea how to do same thing using regular expression while doing mkdir

Comment: Regular expressions are to match something. I understand you want to generate some names, not match existing whatever. I think a shell loop may help, but a loop that generates what `RUN{1..3}` would generate in Bash would be an overkill: just type `RUN1 RUN2 RUN3`. If your problem is more complicated than `RUN{1..3}` then please [edit] the question and state it clearly. Additionally all relevant information from your comments should be in the question body. The question should be standalone.